# Multiplying an input on a textbox and showing the answer on an alert (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an alert box to show up with the result of a multiplication operation when the user clicks on the submit button but I can't seem to get it right

```js
function formAlert3() {
  var x = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  var result = x * 120;
  alert(result);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form3" onsubmit="formAlert3(); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="tel">quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Send" data-theme="b">
```

Comment: The `<input>` is not inside the `<form>`, so it’s not submitting anything. Do you really need this as a submit action?

Answer (score 1):

The submit button is outside the form.It need to be inside the form

```js
function formAlert3(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var result = document.getElementById('quantity').value * 120;
  alert(result);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form3" onsubmit="formAlert3(event)">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="tel">quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Send" data-theme="b">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

1. Call the `formAlert3()` function from the `onclick` event on the submit button
2. Out of the input `formAlert3` you get a string, so you can use the [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert it into a number

Code:

```js
function formAlert3() {
  var x = document.getElementById('quantity');
  var result = +x.value * 120;
  alert(result);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form3">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="tel">quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
  </fieldset>
</form>
<input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Send" data-theme="b" onclick="formAlert3()">
```